# C - For loop ending early after first iteration

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am having an issue with a c assignment where I would ask for the first and last names of a person and their salary. For the most part the loop works when asking for the names as I have tested it and the loop will end when user enters 50 names or until user enter an empty line. The problem comes from when the salary input. When a salary number is entered, the loop just ends. it stops when its supposed to continue until I hit the break or meet the condition.

This is the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter employees first name.\n ");
    gets(charFirstName[i]);
    if (charFirstName[i][0] == '\0')
    { 
        break;
    }
    else
    {       
        printf("Enter employees last name.\n ");
        gets(charLastName[i]);

        printf("Enter employees salary.\n ");
        scanf("%d", &intSalaries[i]);

        intArrayCount++;

    }
}
```

the part where its asking for the salary is where the problem is. I know there is something missing from it but im not entirely sure what. I do know just from trying it that on its own, it wont run properly. Can anyone give me some help and/or advice as to how to fix the issue and add in the part that its missing.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &intSalaries[i]);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &intSalaries[i]);` : `%*c` for consume a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit "Enter" keyboard after entering salary, the "Enter" keyboard input is considered an input and it gets carried over to charFirstName.

One way to get rid of this is as follows:

```
char garbage[50];
```

Add a new line after scanf()

```
scanf("%d", &intSalaries[i]);
gets(garbage);
```

garbage variable will capture "Enter" keyboard input.
Now you are clear for next input.

Comment: Using `gets` is discouraged. You could adopt @bluepixy's format specifier [trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691254/c-for-loop-ending-early-after-first-iteration#comment74428609_43691254).